# itextsharp combobox selection changed in pdf

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0, itext

I have two combobox in PDF and based on the selected item of first combobox , items of second combobox should get updated.
I am unable to find the selected item changed even in itextsharp.
Please let me know how can I achive this